# Add external javascript file in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to add more than one external javascript files in wordpress theme, I have found code for adding one file, but I need to add more javascript files.
How can I do it?

```
function wpTan_scripts() {
   wp_register_script('app', '/js/app.js', false);
   wp_enqueue_script( 'app' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpTan_scripts');
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can add as many scripts as you want.

```
function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-v-2', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mycustomJs', 'file_name.js', false );
    // here you can enqueue more js / css files 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );
```